# 17670 lithium ion cells

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I took apart a very old laptop and the cells I found inside the battery were 17670 (the full name is SF US17670GR). I was planning on using them for a DIY power bank from aliexpress, but the industry standard of lithium ion cells is 18650.

So I want to know if I can safely stick 17670 cells into a 18650 power bank regarding both size and safe charging

Comment: With enough brute force anything is possible.

Comment: I meant to ask regarding safe charging, not size, I will edit my question to make that clear

Comment: For that you have to check if the nominal voltage, maximum voltage, minimum voltage, maximum charging current and maximum discharge current is compatible.

Comment: If you Google a bit you can **easily** find the size of an 18650. Compare that to the size of your 17670. Since the laptop is very old, the cells will have worn out. I seriously doubt if it makes sense to re-purpose such worn-out cells.

Comment: The sizes are in the number: an 18650 is 18 mm in diameter, 65 mm long, and the 0 I believe indicates that the cell is sylindrical. It follows that a 17670 is a cylindrical cell of diameter 17 mm and length 67 mm. But if the question is about the electrical/chemical properties, I don't know why the question focuses on the physical size.

Comment: I checked the voltage on them and all 8 were around 3.2 volts, which according to my googling is pretty good...

Comment: *I checked the voltage on them and all 8 were around 3.2 volts* Hmm, well in my opinion if you keep Li-Ion cells (which these are) at 3.2 V for a long time, it is very likely that they're 90% worn out. If they were 3.5 V or more per cell they might be in a good state, but at 3.2 V I have my doubts. Sure you can use them in a power bank but don't be surprised if the charge they can hold is not enough to fully charge a decent phone. Yes even when there are 4 cells in parallel.

Comment: I thought 17670  cells were supposed to be 3S or 11.2V max

Comment: In my opinion, using random cells to build power packs is a waste of time unless you are able to confirm that the cells have at least 90% of original capacity, and that the series resistance is reasonable. Because otherwise the cells are just going to wear out. Once they wear out, capacity falls very rapidly as you charge and discharge them. If they are already at 80% of original capacity, then in no time at all they will be at 50%. Why invest effort in something that will only give you a few months of use?

Comment: If you currently have no idea what their original capacity is, nor what their capacity is now, and don't have a way to measure capacity and resistance, then you should either invest in a battery cycler, or just buy a good power bank from a reliable source.